# Is there anything like svn_load_dirs.pl for git?

Tags: git, svn

Sometimes we use third party code. But the repositories of these codes are not accessible to us, which means they are only released in a tarball. In such cases, svn_load_dirs.pl is a very handy script to commit such codes to a vendor branch and make fake history at out side. This will make merge easier.
My question is that is there anything alike for git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem really needed with Git:

Each third-party can be stored in its own git repo, and referenced in your main repo [as a submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).
See more at "[Vendor Branches in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769786/vendor-branches-in-git)".

Or you can create a vendor branch, and import it there, as in "[How do I import a third party lib into git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695925/how-do-i-import-a-third-party-lib-into-git)".

In both cases, updating the content is quite straightforward:
Just delete everything, unzip the new version and `git add .`: git will detect the evolutions, removal and additions.

Comment: Yes, it works. I'm happy that git correctly handles these changes, especially files that are removed. With svn you should explicitly remove these files or you'll get a messy vendor code. That's why svn_load_dirs.pl exist. Thank you.